# SSL Certificate Replacement

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

We have an existing Silverlight Applicationa and a SharePoint site. This site was configured as SSL thus it requires SSL Certificate. We want to replace the certificate. Is it possible to replace the certificate from different certificate authority?

Example:

Current Certificate:

- Certificate Autority Issuer: **SomeCertAutority.com**
- Issued to (Target FQDN): **mySite.SomeCertAutority.com**

Replace it with the following:

- Certificate Autority Issuer: **OtherCertAuthority.com**
- Issued to (Target FQDN): **mySite.SomeCertAutority.com**

Will it still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work as long as other CA is trusted by client. In the case of commercial CA, it will work definitely. In the case of private CA, you have to make sure that all clients trust that CA.